# Javascript: Can I find the index of a number in an array based on a prompt input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, prompt, indexof

Is there a way to use the input from a prompt as the index of an array, then create a new array without this number?

What I have so far looks like this, and the index I get is -1:

```
var remNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var input = prompt("pick a number" + " ");
var position = remNum.indexOf(input);
alert("this is the index of your input: " + position);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [convert the user input to a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), because [`prompt()` returns a String.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt)

```
var remNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var input = parseInt(prompt("pick a number" + " "), 10);
var position = remNum.indexOf(input);
alert("this is the index of your input: " + position);
```

---

Note that, for debugging code, [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) (as part of [the larger suite of dev tools that ship with your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20how%20to%20debug)) is *much* more efficacious than `alert()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = parseInt(prompt("pick a number" + " "), 10); //convert to int!
var newArray = [];
for (var i=0; i<remNum.length; i++) {
    if (i != input) newArray.push(remNum[i]);
}
```

This will loop through the array and push all numbers that do not have the index of the prompt. It will also make sure the input cannot run out of bounds.

Comment: @MattBall the OP said "then create a new array without this number?" I assumed they wanted to keep the original array intact?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've converted the input to integer:

```
var remNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var input = parseInt(prompt("pick a number" + " "));
```

You can use `splice()` to remove the element:

```
var position = remNum.indexOf(input);
remNum.splice(position, 1);
```

Error checking is left as an exercise for the reader.